# Hacking a Bluetooth headset

Tags: android, python, networking, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

So I have a Samsung HM1300 (http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones-accessories/BHM1300NBACSTA).

I would like to hack this device, and transmit the button data from the call button for something else. Is this possible? I am just starting to learn about bluetooth, and I am not sure what is possible/not possible.

To be more clear, the device currently has volume up/down buttons and also a talk/accept call button. I would like to pair the device with my computer or android device (whichever is easier), and have some script/app running that receives all the bluetooth commands that are sent over. If someone presses the call button, the script/app should receive that data and do some action.

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Think about it. The information your device sends is to the android os. You could somehow go about and make a listener for the event, but the android/pc, would still (to my knowledge) handle the information. This is due to the different "control" signals being send as there is a standardization for it. This makes it a I/O signal that the user cant do nothing with. Same goes with the normal cord headset.

Comment: Have you done this before? Any links to verify this?

Comment: I don't fully understand Android (first-time dev), but I'm trying to understand this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819649/how-to-capture-key-events-from-bluetooth-headset-with-android

Comment: ^Above post is about the play, pause, rev, ffwd buttons. As far as i can tell. And as i understand it you want to capture the events from the eq. pickup phone.
If you look at the different protocols [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) on wiki, it seems like that the headset uses TSC protocol for controls for the establishment for picking up the phone. That being said as it is middleware anything should be possible.
I would like to point out that this has nothing to do with a specific device as it is a event on the phone you will need get a hold of.

Comment: Currently, when i click the "pickup/call button", my phone immediately dials the last called number. I would like to trap that button event, and start playing music to the headphones. Is this possible?

Comment: If it is possible, please attach any links or resources so I can start looking into the actual implementation. Thanks!