# Headphone button control in Titanium

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Anyone know if there's a **way to control the buttons on both regular and bluetooth headsets**?

I want to use the regular *answer button* to play/pause the current media that I'm playing through the `Ti.Media.AudioPlayer`.

I've tried to get the `Ti.Android.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` to work on Android but without any success the *BroadCastListener* isn't firing when i press button on either a regular headset or a bluetooth headset.

For iOS I have no clue if this is possible to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS if you set the [audioSessionCategory](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media-property-audioSessionCategory) to PLAYBACK and the controls on your headset should interact with the music you're playing.

For Android it looks like you'd need a module to expose a broadcast receiver that would pick up the events [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17983446/4626813). I couldn't find an existing module that does this already.