# Change volume key function in android app

Tags: java, android

I have source code for SmartMouse android app. 
I want to alter the function of volume keys with the onscreen buttons. 
I have basic knowledge for C programming but don't know java. 
What part should I search for in the code?

This might be a lame question but I badly need this.

Answer (score 4):

You have to capture the event as mentionned here : [Android - Volume Buttons used in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874743/android-volume-buttons-used-in-my-application)

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
int action = event.getAction();
int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //TODO
        }
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //TODO
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

dispatchKeyEvent is not only called for volume keys, it will catch all the key event so you have to :

- Get the event code
- Check if it's what you are seeking for
- Do what you want according to the event :)

The key is dispatchKeyEvent is called before any other method by the system, so you can intercept the event

Comment: `diapatchKeyEvent` is for volume keys?

Comment: @PlumillonForge how does calling it before any other method helps in intercepting the event.

Comment: Because the system won't be able to perform the volume up / down anymore :o You can try with onKeyDown to see the difference