# play audio with animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I am working on application when touch it, it plays audio. But after 10,14 times later it not working, any idea ?

// on touch method

```
   img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                anim_value = true;
                handler.post(runnable);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                anim_value = false;
                handler.post(runnable);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

// play inside thread

```
   Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (anim_value) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                    R.raw.tasbi_tick_tick);
            mp.start();
            tasbiCounts = (1 + tasbiCounts);
            tasbeeh_count.setText(tasbiCounts);
            animationTasbeeh.start();
            Log.d("AUDIO", "CALL");
        } else {
            animationTasbeeh.stop();
            mp.stop();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                    R.raw.tasbi_tick_tick);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: "But after 10,14 times later it not working", what not working? audio mot working? animation not working?

Comment: why are you creating a new `MediaPlayer` each time in `Runnable runnable` ?

Comment: because inside oncreat it does not work.

Comment: it works, whats the difference?

Comment: i want to play audio continuously as user touch the screen

Comment: btw why dont you use SoundPool?

Comment: it work for 12,14 but after that it not working

Comment: btw why dont you use SoundPool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their have may solution according to your question

**method-1** simply you can override on touch method by touching sound is started.

**method-2** you can also use runnable tread or run method

**method-3** here we run a thread whenever you touch view, it check isPress or not if view is touched then sound is repeated until unless when you release view from touch.

Your solution [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074484/play-sound-continuously-ontouch/30045258#30045258)