# How can i use the the physical volume button on the phone to change the volume of applications?

Tags: android

I use android.media.MediaPlayer to play some sounds in my app, but when i press the physical volume button, it only changes the system volume (ringtone volume). I searched in google but i haven't had any idea yet.
I use android.media.MediaPlayer not Audiomanger.

Comment: Googled "android register app volume", result: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html

Comment: but i use android.media.MediaPlayer not Audiomanger

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Volume Buttons used in my application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874743/android-volume-buttons-used-in-my-application)

Comment: oh. i tried , but it deny my sound control ( can not change app volume)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the following right before you start playing music

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

and call the following after you finish

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
```

This makes your volume rocker control all music streams and then resets it to default behavior (depends on what's happening).

Don't forget to call `myMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)` before `myMediaPlayer.prepare()`. Replace `STREAM_MUSIC` in both calls with some other value if it fits the played sound better. This makes the music you play conform to the music volume set in system, which is now controlled by the volume rocker.

**Source:**

http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType(int)

Comment: oh. it worked , thanks. even though it took another error, but i have to put these codes to my app.