# Opening Activity from anywhere using buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I am working on an App that should perform a function when a certain sequence of buttons are pressed from anywhere in an Android device. For example, if the volume down button is hold pressed for more than 10 seconds and activity in the app will start.

I have been looking up stuff, and all I seem to get is how you can listen to the button press whilst the App is open. Kindly, help on how I can do this with the App closed, or at least in background.

Comment: check this answer -https://stackoverflow.com/a/33279802/5413981

Comment: Thank you, @VishalVasani. However, I am looking for how I can perform such a Code, so that even if when the App is Closed, a similar function can be called.,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to launch activity of your app on a physical button press. eg. volume up/down button.

I recently developed an app that starts with long press of the volume up button.

I used the android's accessibility service to achieve this.
Here is the official documentation how you can use accessibility service in your app: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#methods

I overridden the onKeyEvent method in my application's accessibility service to receive the key event and added a custom implementation to get the long press functionality.

```
protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); }
```